# Classifier 'Error' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here

Tags: kotlin, android-paging-3

I am trying to add LoadStateListener. But I am getting the error "Classifier 'Error' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here" for LoadState.Error . Below is the code snippet.

```
adapter.addLoadStateListener { loadStates ->
                    when {
                        loadStates.refresh ==LoadState.Error ->{   ----->Gives error here
                            
                        }
                        loadStates.refresh == LoadState.Loading -> {
                            binding.loadingAnimationProgressbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        }
                        loadStates.append == LoadState.Loading -> {
                            binding.loadingAnimationProgressbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        }
                        else -> {
                            binding.loadingAnimationProgressbar.visibility = View.GONE
                        }
                    }
```

Can someone tell what is the issue here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [`LoadState` class](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:paging/paging-common/src/main/kotlin/androidx/paging/LoadState.kt;l=36?q=LoadState&sq=). 
While the `LoadState.Loading` is an object, `LoadState.Error` is a class and thus you must use `loadStates.refresh is LoadState.Error` syntax for it.